# how to setup shared hosting mail in laravel as it is unable to send email from the registered webmail

Tags: email, laravel-5, shared-hosting, webmail

I am unable to understand how should i configure my webmail to send email from laravel as I am using shared hosting(Bigrock).

Please help me to solve the laravel configuration issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create a webmail in your hosting.
Then got to Configure Mail Client. Here you can find details for your mail configuration. And add the information in .env file smtp, port.

Comment: I have already created the webmail in my hosting. but the issue seems to be with my .env configuration file. It is unable to send the email can u please share me the example of .env configuration file??

Comment: give your .env configuration for sending mail.

Comment: thank for asking but I have figured out the problem. The issue was with my security settings and MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS settings in mail.php